# How does the CSS position on a div affects position of sibling division?

Tags: html, css

I have been going through [CSS Positions articles on Alistapart](http://alistapart.com/article/css-positioning-101). Below snippet caught my attention and couldn't fathom the theory behind.

Below html/css shows two boxes one over other. But if I change the position of #box_1 to absolute, then #box_2 overlap #box_1.

```
<!DOCTYPE html >
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <style>
        #box_1 { 
            position: relative;
            width: 200px;
            height: 200px;
            background: #ee3e64;
        }
        #box_2 { 
            position: absolute;
            width: 200px;
            height: 200px;
            background: #44accf;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="box_1"></div>
    <div id="box_2"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

1. How does the position of another box (box_1) affects position of a different/sibling div(box_2). Isn't 'absolute' should always absolute only to immediate non-static parent?
2. In the above css (with "position: relative;" in box_1), if I add "top: 0;" to #box_2, then box_2 appears to overlap again. Why does this happens?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An absolutely-positioned element will remain in its static position if you don't specify *any* of its `top`, `right`, `bottom` or `left` properties, regardless of whether any of its ancestors is positioned. That's why nothing appears to happen to `#box_2` when you simply set it to `position: absolute` — instead, it's affected by `#box_1` in the same way as if you hadn't specified `position: absolute`.

However, note that `#box_1` affects `#box_2` only because 1 precedes 2; once you absolutely position `#box_2` it is taken out of the flow and any siblings that follow it will flow as if `#box_2` was no longer there. See [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/BoltClock/PUTAF) where I create a `#box_3` that's identical to `#box_1` and add it *after* `#box_2`, in which `#box_3` overlaps `#box_2` because 3 doesn't see 2 in the normal flow; it only sees 1.

Once you set `top: 0` to `#box_2`, then it knows it has to be attached to the top of the viewport (as its containing block since none of its ancestors are positioned).

Comment: Ah, thats what I'm looking for ("An absolutely-positioned element will remain in its static position if you don't specify any of its top, right, bottom or left properties"). Thanks a bunch and +10 up votes; if only sf allows it :)

Comment: That's great to know, but is there a solution to display the #box_3 normally with the #box_2 positioned absolute please! @BoltClock

Answer (score 0):

The CSS position on a div does not affects position of sibling division, but it affects the child elements. For Example:

HTML:

```
  <div id="parent_1">
     <div id="child_1"></div>
     <div id="child_2"></div>
  </div>
```

CSS:

```
  #parent_1{ 
        position: relative;
        width: 400px;
        height: 400px;
        background: gray;
    }
 #child_1 {
    position: absolute;
    left:20px;
    top:20px;
    width:40px; 
    background:yellow;
 }
#child_2 {
    position: absolute;
    right:20px;
    top:20px;
    width:40px; 
    background:blue;
 }
```

now **#parent_1** will create a box 400*400 and **#child_1** will be place inside parent div and will positioned 20px from left and 20px from top.

Comment: how does this relates/answer to the question anyway ?

Comment: your questions was "CSS position on a div affects position of sibling division?", my answer is NO it does not, it only affects child-divisions/child-elements only.