# Why is a div with "position: absolute" not by default relative to the document?

Tags: css

I thought a general rule is that, whenever a div `foo` has `position: relative`, then if none of the parent and ancestor has any non-static `position` (so need to have one of `relative, absolute, or fixed`), then, the div `foo` now will be position relative to the overall document.

But in the following page:

http://jsfiddle.net/4RcEn/6/

```
<div id="box1"></div>
<div id="box2">
    <div id="box3">some text inside some text</div>
</div>

<style>
  #box1 { width: 300px; height: 100px; background: #ffd; margin-left: 60px }
  #box2 { width: 300px; height: 100px; background: #fa0; margin-left: 60px }
  #box3 { width: 100px; height: 80px; background: #af0; position: 
          absolute; left: 20px;  }
</style>
```

`box3` actually behave like this: the `left` is `20px` and is relative to the document, but `top` is `auto` (by default), and is in fact relative to the **container div**.  Only when `top` is set to `0`, `0px`, or some other value, then it is relative to the document.  What rule is governing this?

**P.S.** with the rules in the spec, I don't see a rule that says: if the `top` or `left` is not specified, then the behavior is such and such.  So this is a de facto standard that if it is not specified, then if there is no "containing block (which is defined as non-static positioned block), then it won't be relative to the "initial block"?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Position absolute but relative to parent](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10487292/position-absolute-but-relative-to-parent)

Comment: What rule is governing this? [Newton's First Law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_laws_of_motion#Newton.27s_first_law)

Comment: Regarding your edit, I edited my own answer to reference this: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#comp-abspos. Here the spec loosely mentions how if no positioned elements are nearby the element should be positioned relative to its container. I guess this only applies when value is `auto`, but I don't believe it mentions that it should only apply then. If a value is specified, as you've mentioned, it seems to position itself to the document instead.

Answer (score 4):

It *is* positioned relatively to the document (that's the reason why `top: 0` moves it all the way to the top), but if you don't set `top` to any value (i.e. you leave it as `auto`), the box has no reason to shift anywhere from its static position (where it would normally sit if you hadn't set `position: absolute`).

See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14828251/how-does-the-css-position-on-a-div-affects-position-of-sibling-division/14828488#14828488) and sections [9.3](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#positioning-scheme) and [10](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html) of the spec. Section 10, in particular, contains all the rules that govern static positioning, and is quite a comprehensive if not overly technical read.

The exact rule that says an element should remain in the static position in such a scenario is in section [10.6.4](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#abs-non-replaced-height). In your scenario, you don't set `top` or `bottom`, but you do set `height`, so the second rule among the six that are listed applies:

> 2. 'top' and 'bottom' are 'auto' and 'height' is not 'auto', then set 'top' to the static position, set 'auto' values for 'margin-top' and 'margin-bottom' to 0, and solve for 'bottom'

So an absolutely-positioned element needs to remain in its normal static vertical position if `top` is not given something other than `auto` — it's not supposed to move itself arbitrarily.

Also, the containing block of an absolutely-positioned element is always either its nearest positioned ancestor if there is one, or the initial containing block.

Comment: the box has "no reason to shift"?  sounds a little bit comical explanation...  what is the formal rule?

Answer (score 0):

From the notes on the [`top` attribute in the CSS 2.1 specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#propdef-top):

> This property specifies how far an absolutely positioned box's top margin edge is offset below the top edge of the box's containing block. For relatively positioned boxes, the offset is with respect to the top edges of the box itself (i.e., the box is given a position in the normal flow, then offset from that position according to these properties).

To me this implies that if no `top` is specified then the box is positioned to the top of its "natural" container (its parent). When `top` *is* specified it's then offset to the closest ancestor with `relative` or `absolute` positioning (which I assume `html` or `body` have by default).

It [then goes on to say](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#comp-abspos):

> ...which cause the top of the outer box to be positioned with respect to its containing block. The containing block for a positioned box is established by the nearest positioned ancestor (or, if none exists, the initial containing block, as in our example).

Comment: The positioning scheme is much more complicated, but it basically boils down to "containing block" having a different definition from what it seems to imply - http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#containing-block

Comment: I've edited my post. It does go on to mention how it's positioned to the nearest positioned ancestor or, if none exist, the initial containing block. I suppose the `auto` value here complies with this rule by positioning to its container, but then when a value is specified it positions itself in relation the body itself - I imagine this varies across different browsers.

Comment: The initial containing block is usually where the viewport is and can be compared to the viewport, but in general it is the container for the root element `html` (whereas `html` and `body` each generate their own boxes). Also, this should not vary across browsers as the spec has an entire section dedicated to box calculations that browsers are expected to follow (section 10). I've edited my answer as well.

Answer (score 0):

It is work div3 is calculating from body not from div2. Because you not specific "top" position of div than div3 get "top" from div2 and make your top point same as top point of div2. When you add atributte "top: 0px;" to dov3 then you see where is div3 and from which element affected div3 position.